Error with import statements in a React application while using jest
I have a react application I am trying to configure jest, It is throwing an error if I use any import statement
C:\.....ui\src\__tests__\demo.test.jsx:1       
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import "@testing-library/react";
                                                                                      ^^^^^^
    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1505:14)

I have gone through the jest documentation and a few videos are still not clear and getting the error
My package.json
{
  "name": "test-ui",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "vite",
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@trimble-oss/modus-icons": "^1.15.0",
    "@trimble-oss/modus-react-components": "^0.36.0-react18",
    "@trimbleinc/modus-react-bootstrap": "^1.2.4",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "date-fns": "^4.1.0",
    "express": "^4.21.1",
    "gulp": "^5.0.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.10.4",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.26.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.26.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.26.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.26.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.4.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^16.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.1",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.7",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "vite": "^5.3.1"
  }
}

and babel.cofig.js
module.exports = {
    presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
};

and jest.config.cjs
/*
 * For a detailed explanation regarding each configuration property, visit:
 * https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
 */

module.exports = {
  // Indicates whether the coverage information should be collected while executing the test
  collectCoverage: true,
  // The directory where Jest should output its coverage files
  coverageDirectory: "coverage",
  // A list of reporter names that Jest uses when writing coverage reports
  coverageReporters: [
    "json",
    "text",
    "lcov",
    "clover"
  ],
  // An array of file extensions your modules use
  moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "jsx", "json", "node"],
  // The test environment that will be used for testing
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  // The glob patterns Jest uses to detect test files
  testMatch: [
    "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)",
    "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)"
  ],
  // A map from regular expressions to paths to transformers
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx|jsx|js)$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.(css)$': '<rootDir>/fileTransform.cjs',
  },
  // Indicates whether each individual test should be reported during the run
  verbose: true,
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: [".jsx"],
};


and vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': '/src',
    },
  },
});

and my test case is
import "@testing-library/react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import Button from "./Button";

test("renders the button with the correct label", () => {
  //   render(<Button label="Click Me" />);
  expect(1).toBe(1);
});

What is the proper way to configure jest while keeping import statements?

I have copied your configs and try to reproduce the error on my machine.
Simplest setup with your configs works ok, I could start the test without any error.
I could meet your error only when I change jest.config like that:
transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx|js)$': 'babel-jest', //deleted here jsx to exlude such files from babel transpilation
  },

or
  transfrom: {}  //exlude all files from transpilation

It seems that in your local setup babel-jest does not transpile jsx files properly (have not idea why). I would try to delete node_modules, package-lock, clean npm cache and reinstall all deps from scratch.
[UPD]
Please check file name of your babel.config.js file. In your test repo there is a typo (bebl.config.js -> should be babel.config.js).
Btw in your question also a type - babel.cofig.js (a typo - letter n is skipped in word config)

Hi, @Andrey I am using node version 17.9.1 locally, even if I change it to 21.x, I am still getting the same error, Could you please use 17.9.1 and try to reproduce

May you upload on github some minimal version of your setup which creates error for you?

Andrey Here is the github repo
link

in your repo there is a typo: bebl.config.js (should be babel.config.js).
In that case your babel-jest does not see config and it not applied for transpilation.
I rename file and all works good. (I updated my response btw)

That exists only in the test code, not in the actual code, I have resolved the problem by adding a specific exclude which caused error
    "/node_modules/(?!(axios)/)"
  ],```
